# Only keep the end of an adress with Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to keep the beginning of an url and delete the rest to show the source. What I'm doing give me a source like this: `https:domainundefined/test1/test2.html`
What I want is something like this: `https:domain.com`

And this is how I tried to proceed, I have no idea what's wrong since I've followed many examples:

`let linkModif = link.replace((/.com.*$/, ".com") || (/.ca.*$/, ".ca") );
let theSource = ($(this).find('dc\\:source').text()) || linkModif;`

I  guess my regex is wrong. Why?

Edit:

I want to take a link like this one: http://app.domain.com/Delete/This/Part/
and only keep http://app.domain.com

Comment: `const url = new URL(myUrl);
`${url.protocol}${url.hostname}``

Comment: "Something like this" is hard to do a regex on, please provide the full URL and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this. Your problem is not clear, But hope this would work for you

```
var link = "https:domain/test1/test2.html"
var modifydomain = link.split('/')[0]

link = link.split('.')
var modifyExnt = link[link.length-1]
var originalLink = modifydomain + '.' + modifyExnt
console.log('originalLink',originalLink)
```

> Modify

```
//Without protocol
var url = "http://app.domain.com/Delete/This/Part ";
var domain = url.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').split(/[/?#]/)[0];
console.log(domain) // app.domain.com

//With protocol
var url = new URL("http://app.domain.com/Delete/This/Part");
var protocol = url.protocol;
var domain = url.hostname;
url = protocol + "//" + domain
console.log("Url...........",url) // http://app.domain.com
```

Comment: I want to take a link like this one: http://app.domain.com/Delete/This/Part/ and only keep http://app.domain.com

Comment: @Steph i have made the changes, i forget to add the protocol, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the expression given to replace() compares two statements and returns the first evaluated to truthy value:

```
(...).replace((/.com.*$/, ".com") || (/.ca.*$/, ".ca")); 
// this is evaluated to .replace(".com") but has no second argument to the replace function, so it returns undefined
```

So, here's a quick fix:

```
let linkModif = link.match(/.com.*$/) ? link.replace(/.com.*$/, ".com") : link.replace(/.ca.*$/, ".ca");
// added a check for the type of domain
```

Cannot say whether the rest of the jQuery code (line 2) works fine without you showing more code.

Comment: I want to take a link like this one: http://app.domain.com/Delete/This/Part/ and only keep http://app.domain.com